# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django

I have a django model that looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    likes       = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,related_name='post_likes')
```

---

With this toggle, a user can like a post.

```
class PostLikeApiToggle(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, slug=None, format=None):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        like_count = 0
        user = self.request.user
        liked = False

        if user in obj.likes.all():
            liked = False
            like_count = 0
            obj.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            liked = True
            like_count = like_count + 1
            obj.likes.add(user) 
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'You liked the post!')
        data = {
            "liked":liked,
            "like_count":like_count
        }
        return Response(data)
```

---

This is the view I am working on:

```
@login_required
def m_userprofieview(request):
    own_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    allposts = Post.objects.all()
    if request.user in allposts.likes.all():
        liked_posts = liked_posts 
    else:
        liked_posts = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        i_form = ProfilePictureUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Your information has been updated !')
            return redirect('/')
        if i_form.is_valid():
            i_form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Your information has been updated !')
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        i_form = ProfilePictureUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form':u_form,
        'i_form':i_form,
        'own_posts_list':own_posts,
        'liked_posts_list':liked_posts
    }
    return render(request,'m_userprofile.html',context)
```

---

I want that every user has a userprofile with a list of posts he liked.

This is what I tried:

```
if request.user in Post.likes.all():
    liked_posts = liked_posts 
else:
    liked_posts = None
```

This returns the following error: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

```
allposts = Post.objects.all()
if request.user in allposts.likes.all():
    liked_posts = liked_posts 
else:
    liked_posts = None
```

This returns the following error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'likes'

How can I check if a user is in obj.likes.all, where obj are all posts and not just one?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you passed `related_name='post_likes'` in your `ManyToManyField` you can access all `Post`s for a user using this related name

```
liked_posts = request.user.post_likes.all()
```